# Java Find oldest model of car by manufacturer, model, and year in ascending order?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to find the oldest model from each car manufacturer in a list of unsorted cars.  I am sorting this list in ascending alphabetical order, by manufacturer, model, and year with the following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter filename");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        File file = new File(input);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        scanner.nextLine();
        ArrayList<Car> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            String[] arr = scanner.nextLine().split("\t");
            list.add(new Car(arr[0], arr[1], Integer.parseInt(arr[2])));
        }


        for (int end = list.size() - 1; end >= 1; end--)
        {
            for (int current = 0; current <= end - 1; current++)
            {
                Car car1 = list.get(current);
                Car car2 = list.get(current + 1);

                int n = car1.make.toLowerCase().compareTo(car2.make.toLowerCase());
                if (n == 0)
                {
                    n = car1.year - car2.year;
                }
                if (n == 0)
                {
                    n = car1.model.toLowerCase().compareTo(car2.model.toLowerCase());
                }
                if (n > 0)
                {
                    Car temp = list.get(current);
                    list.set(current, list.get(current + 1));
                    list.set(current + 1, temp);
                }
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Oldest cars by make");
        Car oldest = null;
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            if (oldest == null)
            {
                oldest = list.get(i);
            }
            if (!list.get(i).make.equals(list.get(i + 1).make) || i == list.size() - 2)
            {

                count++;
                System.out.println(String.format("%15s%25s%5s", oldest.make, oldest.model, oldest.year));
                oldest = null;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count + " result(s)");
    }
}
```

When I input cars-full.txt (https://www.dropbox.com/s/ahqco56lp3jyuk0/cars-full.txt?dl=0), the unsorted list becomes properly sorted, as you can see here:  (https://www.dropbox.com/s/dcrn8bfhxt4d998/cars-full-sorted.txt?dl=0)

After sorting this list, I am determining the "oldest" model for each manufacturer by the oldest year, and if there are multiple models from the same year, sorting by ascending alphabetical order of the model name.  Here is a picture of my output (right), versus the expected output according to my teacher (left), using the cars-list.txt as input that is linked above:

[image]

Notice how his "oldest" model of Land Rover is Discovery, which shares a manufacturing year with the Defender, and as far as I know, e comes before i, so the Defender should be the output.  My theory is that my professors back end code is checking against a version of cars-full.txt which does not including the Land Rover Defender.

This same professor had an incorrect output for the 100th Fibonnaci index, so it has happened in the past that their backend code that checks my homework automatically has had bugs.

Who is wrong, me or them?  And if it's me, how can I correct my code?

Comment: You can for sure consider De is lower than Di, because of alphabet. It's so simple.. Probably the professor's txt is not the same as yours.

Comment: Well, the oldest Land Rover models in the list are a '94 Defender and a '94 Discovery.  But the '94 Discovery appears earlier in the _unsorted_ list than _any_ of the Defenders.  So profs algo probably just ran the list from top to bottom, looking only at mfr and year and the first Land Rover it sees is a '94 Discovery and no older Land Rover follows, so that's the one that it picked.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Thanks for the insight and taking a look at the lists, I think you might be onto something there.

Comment: @KevinAnderson but in that case *`Land Rover Discovery 2012`* would be the output. Because this entry is at the beginning and *`Land Rover Discovery 1994`* is at the end. Probably this wouldn't be the case here. Because without the sorting other manufacturers would also give wrong output.

Comment: And looking at the dataset, I can see that *`Land Rover Defender 1994`* is at 74th line and *`Land Rover Discovery 1994`* is at the 927th line. Which means the '94 Defender comes before '94 Discovery in the *unsorted* list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation seems correct. I just want to recommend a minor change here. Instead of writing a custom comparator for sorting the `Car` list. You can do it in one line like this:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Car::getMake).thenComparing(Car::getModel).thenComparing(Car::getYear));
```

It will make your code less verbose and concise.

And you're also right that `"Defender"` will always come before `"Discovery"` lexicographically unless the *`Land Rover Defender 1994`* row is missing in the dataset, which might be the case here.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and I like you suggestion.  I just need to submit code that is within what has been taught so far in my class, and sadly this has not been introduced.  For a more advanced Java programmer though, I like that.

Comment: @DavidStampher Well, then you might have to stick with your own implementation. Probably it might be helpful for somebody else in the future. And you don't have to worry about the mismatch in the output. Probably the dataset is change here, otherwise `Discovery` can't come before `Defender` lexicographically.